# Update index after sorting data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

Take the following data-frame:

```
x = np.tile(np.arange(3),3)
y = np.repeat(np.arange(3),3)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
```

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  0
3  0  1
4  1  1
5  2  1
6  0  2
7  1  2
8  2  2
```

I need to sort it by `x` first, and only second by `y`:

```
df2 = df.sort(["x", "y"])
```

```
   x  y
0  0  0
3  0  1
6  0  2
1  1  0
4  1  1
7  1  2
2  2  0
5  2  1
8  2  2
```

How can I change the index such that it is ascending again. I.e. how do I get this:

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  2  1
8  2  2
```

I have tried the following. Unfortunately, it doesn't change the index at all:

```
df2.reindex(np.arange(len(df2.index)))
```

Comment: If you don't need a new df, try `df.sort(["x", "y"], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You can *reset* the index using [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get back a default index of 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 (and use `drop=True` to indicate you want to drop the existing index instead of adding it as an additional column to your dataframe):

```
In [19]: df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

In [20]: df2
Out[20]:
   x  y
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  2  1
8  2  2
```

Comment: That was super helpful.  exp_data=exp_data.reindex(['year'],axis='columns') kept the old index.  Drop removes the old index.

Answer (score 79):

Since pandas 1.0.0 [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) has a new parameter `ignore_index` which does exactly what you need:

```
In [1]: df2 = df.sort_values(by=['x','y'],ignore_index=True)

In [2]: df2
Out[2]:
   x  y
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  2  1
8  2  2
```

Comment: I think this is new in version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 14):

`df.sort()` is deprecated, use `df.sort_values(...)`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Then follow joris' answer by doing `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 6):

You can set new indices by using [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df2.set_index(np.arange(len(df2.index)))
```

*Output:*

```
   x  y
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  2  1
8  2  2
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, use `reset_index()` instead

Comment: Unnecessary, but maybe the most convenient way if you want your index starting at 1 instead of 0 (just add 1 to the argument of set_index)

Answer (score 6):

The following works!

1. If you want to change the existing dataframe itself, you may directly use

   ```
    df.sort_values(by=['col1'], inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    df
    >>     col1  col2  col3 col4
        0    A     2     0    a
        1    A     1     1    B
        2    B     9     9    c
        5    C     4     3    F
        4    D     7     2    e
        3  NaN     8     4    D
   ```
2. Else, if you don't want to change the existing dataframe but want to store the sorted dataframe into another variable separately, you may use:

   ```
   df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['col1']).reset_index(drop=True)

   df_sorted
   >>     col1  col2  col3 col4
       0    A     2     0    a
       1    A     1     1    B
       2    B     9     9    c
       3    C     4     3    F
       4    D     7     2    e
       5  NaN     8     4    D

   df
   >>       col1  col2  col3 col4
         0    A     2     0    a
         1    A     1     1    B
         2    B     9     9    c
         3  NaN     8     4    D
         4    D     7     2    e
         5    C     4     3    F
   ```