# How to index a date column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in a python dataframe. I want to index these by ordering the date. Is this something possible in python?

```
date     indexed
2007-02-21  3
2007-02-18  1
2007-02-24  5
2007-02-18  1
2007-02-23  4
2007-02-20  2
2007-02-23  4
```

I was looking for indexation, but i guess i am using a wrong term to check for. Please guide.

**Edit**

Actually i want to replace the dates by the equivalent index numbers.

Comment: yep, you need to sort them by date, after that index them all using a simple loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update index after sorting data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165734/update-index-after-sorting-data-frame)

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='Date')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to use [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
In [190]: df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['date'], sort=True)[0] + 1

In [191]: df
Out[191]:
        date  indexed  new
0 2007-02-21        3    3
1 2007-02-18        1    1
2 2007-02-24        5    5
3 2007-02-18        1    1
4 2007-02-23        4    4
5 2007-02-20        2    2
6 2007-02-23        4    4
```

PS `pd.factorize()` starts counting from `0`, so i've added `1` in order to meet your desired result

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why do we add 1 here? kindly clarify

Comment: @DoubtDhanabalu, `pd.factorize()` starts from `0`. So i've added `1` in order to meet your desired result

Comment: ok i got it, Thanks a lot. I am accepting this answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is sort_values by date

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["2007-02-21","2007-02-18","2007-02-24","2007-02-18","2007-02-23","2007-02-20","2007-02-23"],columns=["date"])
```

[image]

```
df.sort_values("date", axis=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas.DataFrame.sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['2007-02-21','2007-02-18','2007-02-24','2007-02-18','2007-
02-23', '2007-02-20' , '2007-02-23'], index=[3, 1, 5, 1, 4,2,4], columns=
['Date'])

print df
         Date
3  2007-02-21
1  2007-02-18
5  2007-02-24
1  2007-02-18
4  2007-02-23
2  2007-02-20
4  2007-02-23


df2 = df.sort_index(axis=0)
print(df2)

         Date
1  2007-02-18
1  2007-02-18
2  2007-02-20
3  2007-02-21
4  2007-02-23
4  2007-02-23
5  2007-02-24
```