# Reset index after sorting data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Take this dataset.**

[image: ![Take this dataset.]

**I sorted the data frame by Cancer_type column which contains [0,1] values,**

`df_genes.sort_values(['Cancer_type'], ascending=True)`

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Then I reset the index.**

```
df_genes.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Resetting index messes up the Cancer_type column.
How should I reset the index keeping the Cancer_type column sorted.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165734/update-index-after-sorting-data-frame) follows same procedure but I'm getting different results.

Comment: `df_genes.sort_values(['Cancer_type'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)` is what you need to do. or rather save your sorted df then reset the index

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

What about this?

```py
df_genes = df_genes.sort_values(['Cancer_type']).reset_index(drop=True)
```