# How to sort .iterrows() values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can't seem to find an answer on this topic. I am trying to sort the values in my queryset. Right now, it's automatically sorted by TICKER_id:

```
TICKER_id
DXJ    -0.5
EWA     1.0
EWC     0.0
EWG    -1.0
EWI    -0.5
EWP    -0.5
EWQ     0.5
EWU     0.0
EWW    -0.5
EWY    -1.0
EWZ     0.5
EZA     0.5
FEZ    -0.5
INDA    0.0
MCHI   -0.5
RSX     0.5
SPY     0.0
TUR    -0.5
```

I feel as if there is a way to sort by iterating through the list using .iterrows().

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: you don't have a `list`, you have some pandas data structure, in which case, you should use the `sort_values` method

Comment: you shouldn't be using iterrows working with pandas

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This data is stored in a list:

Comment: What you are showing is not a list, and you've tagged this with `pandas`, so i'm pretty sure it isn't a list. if you want to sort a list, you just use the `sorted` function. or the `.sort` method on a list, which will sort in-place

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, Pandas uses the index to control `itterows` and will therefore go back to the normal order, even if you've resorted the dataframe, because the index goes with the row.

I've been able to iterate over the df in the intended order by [resetting the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
#%%
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"TICKER_id": "DXJ", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWA", "val": 1.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWC", "val": 0.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWG", "val": -1.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWI", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWP", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWQ", "val": 0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWU", "val": 0.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWW", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWY", "val": -1.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "EWZ", "val": 0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "EZA", "val": 0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "FEZ", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "INDA", "val": 0.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "MCHI", "val": -0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "RSX", "val": 0.5},
        {"TICKER_id": "SPY", "val": 0.0},
        {"TICKER_id": "TUR", "val": -0.5},
    ]
)

df.plot() # 1

#%%
df.sort_values(by="val", ascending=False, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.plot() # 2

#%%
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(row.TICKER_id) == 3:
        plt.scatter(index,row.val, c="r")
    else:
        plt.scatter(index,row.val, c="b") # 3
```

This gives:
1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

[This question is related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165734/update-index-after-sorting-data-frame).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you just need `.sort_values()`?

I.e. `dat.sort_values()` or `dat.sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: I've tried that. I am getting a KeyError: 'TICKER_id'. `lag_scores.sort_values(by=['TICKER_id'], inplace= True)`

Comment: You need to get rid of “by=[‘TICKER_id’]” when sorting on a Series.